# Required fields are missing: [TopicId]

Tags: php, php-toolkit

I tried to insert data to salesforce but it returns

> Required fields are missing: [TopicId]

Here is my code in inserting the data:

```php
$tObject = new Stdclass();
            $tObject->EntityId = 'Account salesforce id';
            $Object->TopicId = 'Topic salesforce id';

            $createResponse = $this->conn->create(array($tObject), 'TopicAssignment');
            var_dump($createResponse);
```

And in my .xml file:

```xml
<complexType name="TopicAssignment">
                <complexContent>
                    <extension base="ens:sObject">
                        <sequence>
                        <element name="CreatedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User"/>
                        <element name="CreatedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
                        <element name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                        <element name="Entity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:sObject"/>
                        <element name="EntityId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
                        <element name="EntityKeyPrefix" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <element name="EntityType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <element name="IsDeleted" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                        <element name="NetworkId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
                        <element name="SystemModstamp" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                        <element name="Topic" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Topic"/>
                        <element name="TopicId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
                        </sequence>
                    </extension>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>
```

Why does it return this error?

Comment: what is the values that are you sending? the TopicID should be filled and looks like that it was not.

Comment: It's a valid salesforce id from account. its just an example

Comment: Is the 3rd line in your provided code a typo, or is that how it actually appears in your code? Setting `topicId` on `$Object` instead of on `$tObject` would explain your issue.

Comment: Ohh!. .It fixed the problem, instead of $tObject I used $Object, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was just one of variable names.

The declared variable was `$tObject`
The line that set topicId was `$Object->TopicId = 'value';`
It should have been `$tObject->TopicId = 'value';`

Note that the incorrect version was missing the 't' at the start of the variable name.